# Boto3 get EC2 instance's volume

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

I am trying to get volume-id list of aws instance using boto 3, I am getting sort of collection manager but I don't know how to get the data inside.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')
instance = ec2.Instance('i-xxxxxx')
volumes = instance.volumes.all()
print volumes
```

The answer I got is:

```
ec2.Instance.volumesCollection(ec2.Instance(id='i-xxxxxx'), ec2.Volume)
```

How I am using the "ec2.Volume" to get the volume id

Thanks,
Cfir.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just an iterable of objects so

```
for v in volumes:
    print(v.id)
```

if you want to get a list of id :

```
l = [v.id for v in volumes]
```

Answer (score 4):

An iterator is returned by `ec2.Instance.volumesCollection`

You can extract the volume ids with code like this

```
volume_id_list=[]
for item in instance.volumes.all():
  volume_id_list.append(item.id)
```

then volume_id_list[0] contains the first disk, volume_id_list[1] the second etc

See https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.volumes

Answer (score 4):

Using an EC2 client:

```
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',
                    aws_access_key_id='XYZ',
                    aws_secret_access_key='XYZ',
                    region_name='us-east-1')
volumes = ec2_client.describe_instance_attribute(InstanceId='i-0b30bea4e05579def',
Attribute='blockDeviceMapping')
```

Answer (score 1):

e.g. you can get the volume ID and size simply by iterating over it.

```
for volume in volumes:
    print (volume.id, volume.size)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error attempting to iterate over volumes

Comment: nevermind.. i added the `.all()` call and got the iteratable object you were citing

Answer (score 0):

You can use cli also. Example I'm trying to get list of root volumes attached

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters "Name=attachment.device,Values=*sda1" --query "Volumes[*].[VolumeId]"  --output text --profile=my_genius_aws_profile
```