# How do I get an available EC2 volume using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create a `Python` script to monitor my multiple `AWS` `EC2` instances and I am using the `Boto3` library.

I have gotten stuck when it comes to finding an available volume, as there is the method which returns the volume Id and total size, as described in: [Boto3 get EC2 instance's volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37324085/boto3-get-ec2-instances-volume).

Comment: Can you provide any code example of what you are trying to do and provide any error messages?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I am using boto3 library couldn't found any method to available/free space in aws instance. Please refer the link mentioned in question as an example of how I am working.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way of checking the available volume in EBS. AWS provides a way to send custom metrics to Cloudwatch using the [Cloudwatch Unified Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).

1. Run the CloudWatch unified agent in all your EC2 instances.
2. Send the custom metric (disk utilization) to Cloudwatch, using the agent.
3. Use boto3 to check CloudWatch metric.

Check [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/mon-scripts.html) for more information